# what should I choose? ngram filter,ngram tokenizer or fuzzy match query?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, tokenize, fuzzy-search

I am a little confused about usage of filter, tokenizer vs query. I can select ngram filter or tokenizer during indexing (through an analyzer) I  can also use multi_field to store different variation of same field for different usage of a query so I should not have concerns about flexibility of this approach as mentioned here: http://jontai.me/blog/2013/02/adding-autocomplete-to-an-elasticsearch-search-application/

when I used ngram filter during analysis of text I gave same result as when I used fuzzy query (even better results, because of edgeNGram option that was not available for fuzzy queries.)

**so when should I use fuzzy query (through fuzziness option or fuzzy_like_this query ..) if using filter (during indexing) and simple match query gets better results and as I read it is more scalable?**

**when should I use ngram tokenizer instead of ngram filter?**

Comment: @demon101 I already mentioned this link in my review